# Java servlet out.write(int) prompts user to save file

Tags: java, heroku

I have this simple code in a Java servlet that works as expected:

```
String input = req.getParameter("input");
out.write(input.getBytes());
```

It pulls the text following ?input in the GET request and prints it on the users browser.

But when I try to do the following, instead of displaying the information, the browser
prompts the user to save a file. What's going on? How can I print the database record 
to the screen?

```
PreparedStatement pre = conn.prepareStatement(GET_RECORD);
pre.setString(1, "1000");
rs = pre.executeQuery();
rs.next();
out.write(rs.getInt(1));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the content type of the response to "text/html". It is likely that the servlet is inferring  "application/octet-stream", which gives the prompt.